# Location (GPS) returning wrong values

Tags: android, lua, gps, coronasdk

I'm just learning the Corona SDK for coding some useful things for private use on my Xperia Z1 compact with Android 5.1.1

I stumbled across the functions for location and gave it a try *(with massive help from the reference and the examples)*.

Latitude, longitude and accuracy and work just fine. The coordinates are very close to my actual position *(about 10 metres)* and they are within the given accuracy *(31.5 metres)*. However, Altitude, Speed and Direction aren't quite right.

When I start the application, the altitude is "right" *(maybe 50 metres too high)* at first, but after a few seconds it switches to zero and stays there. This also happens when I "minimise" the application for a short moment and re-open it again.

The speed and direction stay zero all the time, even when I move around.

Here is "my" (mostly copied) code:

```
local display = require ("display")

local t0 = display.newText("Latitude", 100, 50, native.systemFont, 16)
local t1 = display.newText("Longitude", 100, 100, native.systemFont, 16)
local t2 = display.newText("Altitude", 100, 150, native.systemFont, 16)
local t3 = display.newText("Accuracy", 100, 200, native.systemFont, 16)
local t4 = display.newText("Speed", 100, 250, native.systemFont, 16)
local t5 = display.newText("Direction", 100, 300, native.systemFont, 16)

local latitude = display.newText( "-", 200, 50, native.systemFont, 16 )
local longitude = display.newText( "-", 200, 100, native.systemFont, 16 )
local altitude = display.newText( "-", 200, 150, native.systemFont, 16 )
local accuracy = display.newText( "-", 200, 200, native.systemFont, 16 )
local speed = display.newText( "-", 200, 250, native.systemFont, 16 )
local direction = display.newText( "-", 200, 300, native.systemFont, 16 )

local locationHandler = function( event )

    local latitudeText = string.format( '%.4f', event.latitude )
    latitude.text = latitudeText

    local longitudeText = string.format( '%.4f', event.longitude )
    longitude.text = longitudeText

    local altitudeText = string.format( '%.3f', event.altitude )
    altitude.text = altitudeText

    local accuracyText = string.format( '%.3f', event.accuracy )
    accuracy.text = accuracyText

    local speedText = string.format( '%.3f', event.speed )
    speed.text = speedText

    local directionText = string.format( '%.3f', event.direction )
    direction.text = directionText

end

Runtime:addEventListener( "location", locationHandler )
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

It all seems right.
1- Altitude with this type of gps wont be accurate, 50m is good accuracy.

2- You have to add direction listener for direction to work:

```
local directionHandler1 = function( event )
        local magneticText = string.format( '%.1f', event.magnetic )
        magnetic.text = magneticText
end

    Runtime:addEventListener( "heading", directionHandler1 )
```

You need all these three:

```
Runtime:addEventListener( "location", locationHandler1 )
Runtime:addEventListener( "heading", directionHandler1 )
Runtime:addEventListener('accelerometer', processor)
```

Comment: My actual altitude should be around 1000 metres, but it returns something around 1040, but that's pretty acceptable... After a few seconds it goes to 0, though...

Comment: As I mentioned, you need special gps unit to get accurate altitudes. Handheld or mobile gps only gives you minimum 5m error for lat and long. Nobody uses it for altitude in real life.